# Why can't I close a Solana program, and redeploy to the same program id?

Tags: pda, deploy, redeploy

```
solana program close -u mainnet-beta <PROGRAMID>
--recipient <RECIPIENT> `

 ...

anchor deploy

Deploying workspace: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
Upgrade authority: {PATH_TO_AUTHORITY}.json
Deploying program {program}…
Program path: {PATH_TO_PROGRAM}.so…
Error: Program {old_id} has been closed, use a new Program Id
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: “”, stderr: “” }.
```

If I still held the keypair to the program ID, why couldn't I redeploy it to that ID?

This seems like a crucial functionality to have if you had PDAs associated with that ID and the program was closed. If you could redeploy to that ID, the value in the PDAs could be recovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, and this is under active discussion in this PR: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/27460

The implementation they are leaning towards would indeed let you recover value in the PDA's if you hold the keypair to the program ID.